# Multiple commands in a bash one-liner using { } -> "unexpected end of file"

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run the following:

```
bash -c "[[ -d foo ]] || { mkdir foo && echo create foo done }"
```

But I get following error:

```
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Why do I get above error? How can I fix it?

Comment: try `...{ mkdir .... ; }` . (Note added `;` char). Good luck.

Comment: A solution should be added *as an answer*, not an edit to the question. You're allowed to add (and accept) your own answers.

Comment: btw, the problem had nothing at all to do with ssh -- you'd need that `;` even to do `[[ -d foo ]] || { mkdir foo && echo create foo done; }` successfully on your local machine.